# XML Schema nested child into any element

Tags: xml, xsd, castle

I'm trying to write XML Schema for this XML structure:

```
<castle>
    <parameters>
        <firstParameter>text</firstParameter>
        <secondParameter>
            <list>
                <item>a</item>
                <item>b</item>
                <item>c</item>
            </list>
        </secondParameter>
        <thirdParameter>
            <array>
                <item>a</item>
                <item>b</item>
                <item>c</item>
            </array>
        </thirdParameter>
        <fourthParameter>
            <parameters>
                <firstParameter>text</firstParameter>
                <secondParameter>
                    <list>
                        <item>a</item>
                        <item>b</item>
                        <item>c</item>
                    </list>
                </secondParameter>
            </parameters>
        </fourthParameter>
    </parameters>
</castle>
```

I do not known how to specify element with any name. My actual XSD looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="parameters">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:any processContents="skip" namespace="##targetNamespace"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But it skips validation in nested parameters level. Do you know how to write it to be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Validation is skipped because you've told it to do so by using `xsd:any` with `processContents="skip"`.  Your other control points would be

- Set `processContents` to `lax` to indicate that element declarations
  should be used if defined but need not be defined.
- Set `processContents` to `strict` to indicate that element
  declarations should be used and must be defined.
- Use XSD 1.1 and create assertions over the `xsd:any` elements.

You can get more restrictive if you fix the elements allowed under parameters by either limiting or parameterizing their names.

Comment: Thank you, I know behavior of `processContents`. What I do not know is how to specify element with wildcard name contains defined element name (list|array|dictionary|parameters) or simple string.

Comment: I do not really need validate XML, but Visual Studio use this XSD to intelliSense purpose.

Comment: You may not need to validate XML, but you still need to abide by XSD rules regarding what constraints can be imposed along with `xsd:any`, which I've tried to convey in this answer.   If you need to specify more structure beyond the discussed provisions, you'll need to avoid `xsd:any` to get more control over the content model.